# How to push string into array of array in Laravel 5

Tags: multidimensional-array, php-7

I used Codeigiter before, i can use

```
$var[index1][index2][] = $string;
```

in a foreach loop, it will keep pushing 
But now i got error "Cannot use string offset as an array"

```
foreach ($grandpa as $index1 => $father){
   $newArr[$index1] = ''; 
   foreach ($father as $index2 => $son){
     $newArr[$index1][$index2][] = $string;
   }
}
```

So that i have the same array structure of grandpa.

Comment: Can you update your question to include a complete runnable example of what yer trying to do, including the input values and an assertion that demonstrates the exd result that you want? Perhaps read sscce.org and http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html. First thing I see is that yer initialising `$newArr[$index1]` as an empty string, and then go on to use it as an array. That's not going to help. Also this is just a PHP question, it's got nothing to do with either CodeIgniter or Laravel, so perhaps revise yer tagging.

Comment: I am trying to create a multidimensional array, which array structure is coping the structure of other object array, 2 level array.

Comment: What i do now, foreach the original object array thought, and use there index to create my other object array